# Powershell: How can I count the lines of output from a command for each of many files?

Tags: powershell

`exiftool` produces multiple lines of output for each file it processes. I want to invoke it on all the jpgs in a directory, and I want to see how many lines are output for each file. Doing this,

```
exiftool *.jpg | measure-object -line
```

gives me the total number of lines of output for all files together, not the number of lines for each file. I also tried this,

```
exiftool *.jpg | foreach{get-content $_ | measure-object -line}
```

but that just showed that I don't know how to use Powershell (i.e., I got a lot of error messages). Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg |
  ForEach-Object { (exiftool $_.FullName).Count }
```

- `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg` outputs file-information objects for each file whose extension is `.jpg` in the current directory.
- [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) processes each file-information object, accessible via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), and passes it to the external `exiftool` program as a full, file-system-native path, via the file-information object's `.FullName` property.
- Given that PowerShell emits the lines output by an external programs *one by one*, which - when collected via `(...)` - amounts to an *array* of lines<sup>[1]</sup>, you can simply invoke `.Count` on that array to get the line count.

  - That said, at least hypothetically, piping to [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) first for output-line counting and *then* applying `.Count` reduces the memory load (because the lines themselves needn't all be collected in memory first), at the expense of execution speed.

---

<sup>[1] With a *single* output line, that line is captured as-is, but PowerShell's unified treatment of collections and scalars exposes a `.Count` property even on *scalars*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = MyCommand
$results | Where-Object{$_.DiffCount -gt 0} | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.